# Django Many-To-One on delete

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, relational-database

In my model structure there are two models.

```
class Message(models.Model)
    #there are some fields
    #...
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')


class User(models.Model)
    # and there
```

We can see that user `has many` messages, when user is deleted, all messages are deleted too, or foreign key is set to null.

The question is, how can i handle last user's message deleting event?
I need doing just something like this on every message deleting?

```
#...
if user.message_set.count() < 1:
    user.handle_last_message_delete()
```

Are there SQL-level solutions(as far as i know, triggers can help, but I'm not sure)?

If there are, what about django ORM compability?

And what solution would you choose, if message adding is much more frequent operation then deleting, and only admins are permitted to delete messages?

P.S. Great thanks in advance.

P.P.S. I also will be very thankful for relational databases theory links.

Comment: > Are there SQL-level solutions(as far as i know, triggers can help, but I'm not sure)? — decide^ are you want sql or ORM engine?

Comment: I'm thinking ORM will be more suitable, because application looks to be reused.

Comment: So I think you should not bother about sql-trigger and implement logic partially with orm, partially with sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to control `message` deletion in wrong place.

Current logical chain:

```
py: user.delete() 
    -> db: delete .. from tuser
        -> db: cascade .. 
            -> db: trigger ..
                -> py: ??? // trying to somehow catch last message
```

In such way business logic is mostly placed in db and not in orm, and there are problem on how to link db events with py callbacks. Or may be not to link them at all and place all logic into db?

If you want to manage deletion with orm, the logic should look like this:

```
py: user.delete():
    py: messages = user.select_all_messages() // get all messages
    py: for msg in messages: msg.delete() // or do what you want to do
        -> sql: delete .. from tmessage
    py: user.really_delete_from_db()
        -> db: delete .. from tuser
            x db: cascade .. // already done
                x db: trigger .. // no need to catch events
```

In this way you firstly delete all dependent objects with full control on their deletion, and only then delete user entries without any unmanageable side-effects

Answer (score 0):

Why do you delete the user ? You just could add a Boolean field to deactivate it. So you won't have to handle your messages issues.

```
class User(models.Model)
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Message(models.Model)
    #there are some fields
    #...
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
```